# read excel file to a dataframe without downloading the file locally

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api

I am trying to read an excel file on a google drive without downloading the file locally

```
credentialFileOfServiceAccount =  'x.json'
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] #edited by ashraf
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credentialFileOfServiceAccount, scope)
print(creds)



 spreadsheetId=file.get("id")
                gauth = GoogleAuth()
                gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
                url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + file_id + "?alt=media"
                res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + gauth.attr[creds].access_token})

# 2. The downloaded XLSX data is read with `pd.read_excel`.
sheet = "Sheet1"
values = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(res.content), usecols=None, sheet_name=sheet)
print(values)
```

that's the error I am receiving

> InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file ('Error opening file', 'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)

Comment: FYI: You are downloading the file into memory your just not saving it to a file on your machine.   Your title is a bit off.   Im a bit confused as to how that code could result in that error.   Error states client_secrets.json, yet your code says x.json.    That being said your code cant find the file client_secrets.json  Make sure that  credentialFileOfServiceAccount actually points to the directory where the file exits.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely related to the fact that you have not set the path properly for your service account credentials file.

I got this to work.

```
#   To install the Google client library for Python, run the following command:
#   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

# Service account key file
KEYFILE = "C:\YouTube\dev\ServiceAccountCred.json";

# file id
FILEID = "1JTbcnbcmuN0olIUJ-FYIHLnSUDePfbw7";

def main():

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        KEYFILE,
        scopes=SCOPES,
    )

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        # assign a variable with the found id name
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=FILEID)
        file = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print(F'Download {int(status.progress() * 100)}.')
            sheet = "Sheet1"
            df = pd.read_excel(file,  engine='openpyxl')
            print(df.head())



    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```